# How would I fix this vent sides that are bending inward?

Tags: vent, ducts

I have a vent with side walls that are bending inward, preventing the vent cover from sitting in the duct properly (it currently just sits on top of the bent portions). I can push the bent portions open, but I'm not sure if I can open it enough and the sides pop back to where they are now after letting go.

Around the vent is concrete, and I'm not able to access the vent or duct from anywhere but from above. The sides are each bending in about 1/2" to 3/4" in the middle. There is some dust and trash that has collected between the duct wall and the concrete (I already pulled out a water bottle cap) from the previous owners.

Is there something I can do to fix the sides to get the vent to sit in the floor properly?

[image: Vent with sides bending inward from above]

[image: Vent cover sitting above the floor]

Answer (score 1):

That probably happened because the vertical opening is too small.

Since normal drill will not work inside the duct you need a attachment like this one.

Now you can driwe some screws in to the studs o the sides and keep the duct straight.

[image: 90 dgr]

Source: [source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09DXWHVK1)

You can also try with some construction glue, and use a pice of wood 4 and 3/4 to insert to push it outwards and leave till glue dries.

Comment: I like the idea, but there are no studs around the vent. All sides are surrounded by concrete.

Comment: @DillonHertz. same difference, just drill in concrete then and use some small (1/4 inch) concrete anchors. You probably only need one hole in the middle on each side to screw in

Comment: Or you just get a narrow block of wood the right length and jam it in there.